# Creating a new object in Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

Following the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data), I want to store a new object (an instance of my `Order` class) on Firebase, and I  want it to create a new key for me. This is what I'm doing:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference orders = database.getReference("orders");
orders.push().setValue(order);
```

But nothing shows up from the console. Do I need to create the `orders` key in advance? I cannot create if manually from the console, because it appears that empty keys aren't valid.

The `Order` class is as follows:

```
public class Order {

    private final ArrayList<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }

    public void addOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem) {
        orderItems.add(orderItem);
    }

}
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments, I checked the error I get:

```
Permission denied
```

But my access rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the rule should apply only to the `users` key, not to the `orders` one. For other keys, the default rules should apply:

> The default rules require Authentication. They allow full read and write access to authenticated users of your app.

My user is authenticated, so why this is not working in my case? How can I ensure that the user is authenticated properly?

In any case, changing the access rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) set to allow access?  The default rules allow access only by authenticated users.

Comment: To detect whether this is the problem, add a completion listener to your `setValue()` call. See [Detect errors when writing a value to Android](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=201608190142309558745) for an example

Comment: @qbix I'm using the default security rules, but the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not support serializing Arraylists. You should use a List or Map instead.
The support Datatypes are:

- String
- Long
- Double
- Boolean
- Map<String, Object>
- List<Object>

You are confusing the default rules for your Database with the default rules that apply to a certain access:

> Note: Access is disallowed by default. If no .write or .read rule is specified at or above a path, access will be denied.
>   Offical Firebase Documentation

To check if the user is signed in you can use this code snippet from the Docs:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

Or you can use a listener to get informed about changes with the AuthState:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```